# Sybase (ASE) DATETIME field in where clause for exact match

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to pass a datetime value to a stored proc query where it is checked against a column which is also a datetime field.

Lets say an example, I have a table which has:

```
ProductID int
ProductName varchar(20)
InsertDate DateTime
```

Now, I write a stored proc:

```
Create proc usp_GetProductsByInsertDate
@input_insertDate datetime
as
select * from Products where InsertDate = @input_insertDate
```

Now, if I pass `@input_insertDate = '07/01/2016 06:25:15 PM'`, it should bring me the list of products which was inserted exactly at that time, but that doesn't happen. I might have to put like below which returns the result:

```
select * from Products where InsertDate >= @input_insertDate
```

I would want to use the "date and time" in where claue field. Can I use that? This might be a silly question, but I would like to know why it doesn't work. Please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the values in your target column `InsertDate` has milliseconds (> 0) in it for your expected matching rows. Some Database IDEs in default settings hide the milliseconds (your `@input_insertDate` does not have milliseconds) which might cause such a confusion. Your query looks fine to me, you can do a `datepart(ms, InsertDate)` on your expected rows to check.

Comment: no, i don't thing so it is related to datepart and there is no milli secs in my target column

Comment: Can you post some data which you are expecting with datepart for millisecond values?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with passing the date as string in the query or parameter while EXEC the stored proc. Looks like it doesn't like a string value for an exact datetime match. When date object is passed internally within the procedure, then it matches and returns the result, i.e., if we query a table for a field which has "datetime", assign that to a variable and pass that variable to the next query for exact match, then it works. Isn't it weird?